# Find most frequent values among infinite possibilities

Tags: algorithm, counting

I have an ongoing stream of values, where the number of different values is extremely large. I would like to find a way to estimate the *M* most frequent values - without keeping track of all values and their counters, as this is not feasible. Also, the stream is live all the time, and so I must keep updating these estimates. Is there an algorithm or a method for this?

Comment: This depends on the accuracy and response you require.  For a start, you can simply sample the streaming input and count what you see there.  How sensitive do you need to be, to changes in the stream?  Is your top-M estimate for all time, periodic, or a moving window?

Comment: See https://www.cs.rutgers.edu/~farach/pubs/FrequentStream.pdf for a technique to do this.

Comment: @btilly thanks this is what I was looking for! feel free to add this as answer so I can accept it :)

Comment: @shakedzy I won't do that because moderators frown on answers that are just external links which can break, and I don't feel motivated enough to type up the contents of the link.